# LocationSettings kitkat emulator result canceled

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm using CheckLocationSettings to check if location is enabled or not. this is working fine on my Galaxy S5. however, on the emulator android kitkat 4.4 the LocationSettingsResult is always 6 ( ResolutionRequired) regardless of whether location is enabled or disabled.
also if i answer the location request popup with YES, the OnActivityResult is always RESULT_CANCELED

i'm using xamarin, so some parts looking different:

```
protected void buildGoogleApiClient()
        {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .AddApi(LocationServices.API)
           .Build();
        }

        protected void createLocationRequest()
        {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

            mLocationRequest.SetInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            mLocationRequest.SetFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            mLocationRequest.SetPriority(LocationRequest.PriorityLowPower);
        }

        protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest()
        {
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
            builder.AddLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
            builder.SetAlwaysShow(true);
            mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.Build();
        }

        protected async Task CheckLocationSettings()
        {
            var result = await LocationServices.SettingsApi.CheckLocationSettingsAsync(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationSettingsRequest);
            await HandleResult(result);
        }


        public async Task HandleResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult)
        {
            var status = locationSettingsResult.Status;
            switch (status.StatusCode)
            {
                case CommonStatusCodes.Success:
                    await getlastknownlocation();
                    break;
                case CommonStatusCodes.ResolutionRequired:

                    try
                    {
                        status.StartResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    }
                    catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException)
                    {

                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SettingsChangeUnavailable:
                    break;
            }
        }


                protected override async void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                    switch (resultCode)
                    {
                        case Result.Ok:
                            await getlastknownlocation();
                            break;
                        case Result.Canceled:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` (C#: `ResolutionRequired`), you need to ask the user for permission.

> A status code of RESOLUTION_REQUIRED indicates that the settings must be changed. To prompt the user for permission to modify the location settings, call startResolutionForResult(Activity, int). This method brings up a dialog asking for the user's permission to modify location settings.

Call `StartResolutionForResult` with a result code that you can check for in `OnActivityResult` to determine if the user granted the permission or not:

```
if (status.StatusCode == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.ResolutionRequired)
{
    status.StartResolutionForResult(this, 9999);
}
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html

Comment: hi, thx for your answer. however, this is already implemented in the code above... try
                    {
                        status.StartResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                    }
                    catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException)
                    {
                    }

Comment: also tried now with a android 5.0 emulator, same result. after accepting the permission request the result is always RESULT_CANCELED and also the permission request message appears  regardless of whether location is enabled or disabled. same as on android 4.4